# Does session dies by going back through "self.location"?

Tags: php, javascript

In my hospitality site ,a visitor searches hotels(those give offer for a particular date range).If he gets zero records for his search criteria,then he edits his search and again searches.when he edits his search he goes back to the page where his previous entered values must be pre-filled.I store those values in the session .But while it goes back,session lost.

There is a search form `search.php`. After clicking the `Search now` button in the 'search.php', I go to `search_result.php` page and  the data brought through the POST value are set in the session in 'search_result.php'.

There is a button called `"Edit Ur search"` in the `search_result.php` page.When I click on it, it should bring me back to `search.php` where the values set in the session must be displayed and the search form must be pre-filled with those session values.

In `search_result.php` I call `edit_search()` on the click event on `"Edit Ur search"` button

```
function edit_search(){

    var url = "hotels.php";

    self.location = url;

}
```

But when I return back to search.php I loss the session value. Is it due `self.location` clearing the session?

I need to persist all those session values.
Any other method to complete the requirement is appreciated.

Comment: nope,this is something else. if you post code, we might figure it out, but some of the causes are you forgot to start_session()  or the code is not even reaching the point of storing in sessions, or the temporary directory where sessions are stored as default is being wiped out too soon or there is session destroy somewhere or cookies are not accepted by your browser.

Comment: `Edit Ur search`.... really? What kind of website is that :D But no, `self.location` is not the problem (might depend on what `hotels.php` is doing).

Comment: Edit Ur Search?? Must be for ucanhazhotelz.com :)

Comment: Both the search.php and search_result.php includes connect_database.php.In connect_database.php "session_start();" is written.I found that this is the reason behind my problem.But plz suggest me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search form is @ search.php page.I saved the search criteria inside database.And when the visitor cliked search button and redirected to search_result.php, I show the search criteria by fetching the data from database.In this way I solved my problem.

This problem can also be solved by managing session_start() in anyother page instead of writing in connect_database.php which is included in both search.php and search_result.php.

But as my client's another requirement was also to save the search criteria for further betterment of the site,hence I followed the 1st option mentioned earlier.

Hence I conclude going back through "self.location" was not the reason behind session dye.Rather it was the session_start() written twice in those 2 concer page was the reason of this problem.
Thanks...........